# FFmpeg : I'm looking for a way to put some blur behind the image by cutting it

Tags: image, ffmpeg, blur, cut

I'm looking to do this effect of blur (in the background) here:

[Blur effect vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqJhS.jpg)

But at a ratio of 1:1. We start with any ration to have a ratio of 1:1

What I have managed to do so far it's that:

Input1 :
[Input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN5BR.png)

Output1:
[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tYPV.png)

Input2:
[Input2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1kh6.jpg)

Output2:
[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P233n.jpg)

With this code:

> ffmpeg -i input.png -vf "scale720:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:720:-1:-1:color=black" output.png

Thank a lot to try to help me because i am very lost with this tool...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @iCrise! It may be easier to get help if you explain clearly what the result/output is that you want - it's not 100% clear from your title, nor your question. As an input, you're receiving images of different sizes and ratios - e.g., some are landscape, some are portrait, some are square, etc. What should the output be? Should they all be outputted with the same ratio? Should they keep their original ratio, but have a specific 'focused' area in the centre (with its own ratio), while the rest is blurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won !!!

This code do perfectly what i ask :

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vg "[0:v]split=2[blur][vid];[blur]scale=720:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=720:720,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[vid]scale=720:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[ov];[bg][ov]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" output.png
```